# Rotate image with Paperclip 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rotation, paperclip

I've got photo on my model

```
has_attached_file :photo, BucketConfig.default.merge(
      processors: [:rotator],
      styles: {
          original: Proc.new { |a| { rotation: a.rotation } }
      },
      default_url:  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('assets/request_default.png')
  )
```

To catch a rotation param I do something like this

```
attr_accessor :rotation

    before_save :adjust_rotation
    before_update :reprocess_image

    protected

    def adjust_rotation
      self.rotation = self.rotation.to_i
      self.rotation = self.rotation % 360 if self.rotation >= 360 || self.rotation <= -360
    end

    def reprocess_image
      self.photo.reprocess! unless self.rotation.zero?
    end
```

my Rotator process in lib/paperclip

```
module Paperclip
  class Rotator < Processor
    def transformation_command
      if rotator_command
        rotator_command + super.join(' ')
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def rotator_command
      target = @attachment
      if target.rotation.present?
        " -rotate #{target.rotation} "
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I call

```
m = Model.first
m.rotation=90
m.save
```

I've got error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  clone:
  paperclip (4.3.7) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:582:in `block in unlink_files'
  paperclip (4.3.7) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:581:in `unlink_files'
  paperclip (4.3.7) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:536:in `post_process_style'
  paperclip (4.3.7) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:511:in `post_process_styles'
  paperclip (4.3.7) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:504:in `block (2 levels) in post_process'
```

Why my reprocess! method doesn't work ? Do I something wrong with my rotator process? Where's the problem?

Comment: any update on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have no make method: https://github.com/rezeko/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/processor.rb#L9

A fix is to use `class Rotator < Thumbnail`, and just inherit the processing setup by the default processor.